# How to use Findbugs omitVisitors?

Tags: gradle, findbugs

I'm using Findbugs together with Gradle. I have a project in witch Findbugs finds a potential bugs.

Bug type ODR_OPEN_DATABASE_RESOURCE
org.kec.db.connection.DBAccess.query(String) may fail to close PreparedStatement.

I can't change the code so I would like to add the bug detector/visitor to the list of OmitVisitors.

As I understand the usage of OmitVisitors it takes a list of class names. My problem is that I can't find a map between the bug type and the class name.

How do I omit the visitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excluding specific errors for some of your analyzed classes may be done with [Findbugs filters](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html). You need to come up with a list of class/bug matches which you want to be excluded. In your case, the XML file would look like this:

```
<FindBugsFilter>
    <Match>
        <Class name="org.kec.db.connection.DBAccess" />
        <Method name="query" />
        <Bug pattern="ODR_OPEN_DATABASE_RESOURCE" />
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

In the Gradle script, the XML file with the excluded bugs needs be set for the [`excludeFilter`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugsExtension.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugsExtension:excludeFilter) property.

```
findbugs {
    excludeFilter = file("$rootProject.projectDir/config/findbugs/excludeFilter.xml")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the findbugs sources and ran

```
find -name *.java | xargs grep -lir ODR_OPEN_DATABASE_RESOURCE
```

it said

```
./src/java/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/detect/FindOpenStream.java
```

So I guess you should use FindOpenStream as name